# can't position div where I want

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey guys I'm making the hours section to a mexican website i'm working on. Im making it all on one page so you just have to scroll down to see all the sections. When i finished the about section i used margin-top: -300px to pull that section up where i needed it, this however does not work with the hours section. The previous menu section pushes it too far down creating unwanted space? I have no clue on how to fix this!? 
https://codepen.io/spabsa/pen/mKZWQa

p.s i have to include code because i have a codepen link but I have too much code which is why i included the link so heres some incomplete code lol

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>El Metate | Mexican Food</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive|Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif|Kumar+One+Outline|Teko" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Diplomata+SC|Ewert|Sarina|Smokum" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <section id="header">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="nav-btn">
    <div class="btn-1"></div>
    <div class="btn-2"></div>
    <div class="btn-3"></div>
   </div> 
    <div class="side-menu">
     <ul>
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#hours">Hours</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   <p><span class="auth">Authentic</span><span class="mexi">Mexican</span><span class="food">Food</span></p>
   <img src="img/LogoMakr_Oso9xi.png" alt="">
  </div>
 </section>

 <section id="about">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="line"></div>
   <h1>About us</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis, quis, adipisci! Unde natus quas officiis, earum commodi! Voluptate in modi alias quisquam maiores sunt fugit reprehenderit odio rem obcaecati libero repellat saepe quidem quibusdam impedit labore error velit, possimus necessitatibus. Optio ullam, officiis, sit ipsa fugiat animi voluptas labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, et.</p>
   <div class="image-slider">
    <i class="fas fa-caret-down left"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-caret-down right"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section id="menu">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="left-border">
    <div class="shape-wrap">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 385px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 770px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1155px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1540px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1925px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 2310px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="right-border">
    <div class="shape-wrap">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 385px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 770px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1155px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1540px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1925px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 2310px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
   </div>

   <h1>Menu</h1>
   <div class="line-2"></div>

   <div class="vexel-images"></div>

   <div class="col-1">
    <h3 class="platter">Combination Platters</h3>
    <p class="platter-info">Rice & Beans Included</p>

    <p class="item item-1">Tostada & Taco</p><span class="price p1"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-2">2 Beef Tacos</p><span class="price p2"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-3">2 Enchiladas</p><span class="price p3"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-4">Tostada & Enchilada</p><span class="price p4"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-5">Taco & Enchilada</p><span class="price p5"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-6">Burrito & Enchilada</p><span class="price p6"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-7">2 Beef Burritos</p><span class="price p7"><span class="s1">$</span>7.45</span>
    <p class="item item-8">2 Carne Asada Tacos</p><span class="price p8"><span class="s1">$</span>8.09</span>
    <p class="item item-9">Chorizo</p><span class="price p9"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-10">Carne Asada</p><span class="price p10"><span class="s1">$</span>8.19</span>
    <p class="item item-11">Machaca</p><span class="price p11"><span class="s1">$</span>6.75</span>
    <p class="item item-12">Carnitas</p><span class="price p12"><span class="s1">$</span>7.19</span>
    <p class="item item-13">2 Fish Tacos</p><span class="price p13"><span class="s1">$</span>6.75</span>
    <p class="item item-14">Chiles Rellenos</p><span class="price p14"><span class="s1">$</span>6.95</span>
    <p class="item item-15">Red Combo</p><span class="price p15"><span class="s1">$</span>7.95</span>
    <p class="item item-16">Green Combo</p><span class="price p16"><span class="s1">$</span>7.05</span>
    <p class="item item-17">3 Rolled Tacos w/Guacamole</p><span class="price p17"><span class="s1">$</span>6.75</span>
    <p class="item item-18">Chimichanga, Rice & Beans</p><span class="price p18"><span class="s1">$</span>7.05</span>
    <p class="item item-19">Carne Asada Burrito</p><span class="price p19"><span class="s1">$</span>7.19</span>
    <p class="item item-20">2 Tamales, Rice & Beans</p><span class="price p20"><span class="s1">$</span>7.05</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-4">Tacos</h3>
    <p class="platter-info info4tacos">Folded</p>

    <p class="item item-21">1 Chicken Taco</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
    <p class="item item-22">1 Beef</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
    <p class="item item-23">1 Carne Asada</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.61</span>
    <p class="item item-21">1 Fish</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
    <p class="item item-22">1 Carnitas</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
    <p class="item item-23">1 Adobada</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
    <p class="item item-23">1 Cabeza</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>

    <p class="platter-info info4tacos">Rolled</p>

    <p class="item item-21">3 Plain with Cheese</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.39</span>
    <p class="item item-22">3 Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.89</span>
    <p class="item item-23">3 Chicken w/Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.89</span>
    <p class="item item-21">3 Tacos w/Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>3.99</span>
    <p class="item item-22">12 Tacos w/Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>8.99</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-7">Tortas</h3>

    <p class="item item-21">Carne Asada</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Machaca</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
    <p class="item item-23">Ham</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.61</span>
    <p class="item item-21">Chorizo</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Chicken</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
    <p class="item item-23">Carnitas</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
    <p class="item item-23">Fish</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-8">Breakfast Served Everyday</h3>
    <p class="platter-info info4breakfast">6am to 11am</p>

    <h3 class="platter plat-9">Breakfast Plates</h3>
    
    <p class="item item-21">Huevos Racheros</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>6.29</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Steaks Racheros</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>6.95</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Scrambled Eggs w/Ham</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>5.95</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Scrambled Eggs w/Suasage</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>5.95</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Chorizo Omelette</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>6.95</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Carne Asada Omelette</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>7.95</span><p class="item item-22">Scrambled Eggs w/Ham</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>5.95</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Eggs and Bacon</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>5.95</span>
   </div>

   <div class="col-2">
    <h3 class="platter plat-2">Enchiladas</h3>

    <p class="item item-21">2 Cheese</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-22">2 Beef</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-23">2 Chicken</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-3">Side Orders</h3>

    <p class="item item-24">Carne Asada Fries</p><span class="price p24"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-25">Jalepenos</p><span class="price p25"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-26">Quesadilla</p><span class="price p26"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-27">Ham Quesadilla</p><span class="price p27"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-28">1/2 Pint of Beans</p><span class="price p28"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-29">1/2 Pint of rice</p><span class="price p29"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-30">Ham Quesadilla</p><span class="price p30"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-31">Super Nachos</p><span class="price p31"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-32">1 Tamale</p><span class="price p32"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-33">Extra Cheese Quacamole</p><span class="price p33"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-34">Supreme Quesadilla</p><span class="price p34"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-35">Chips and Quacamole</p><span class="price p35"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-36">1 Chiles Rellano</p><span class="price p36"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-37">Chips & Salsa</p><span class="price p37"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-38">Churros</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Burrito Asada R&B</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-40">1/2 Pint of Beans</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-41">1/2 Pint of rice</p><span class="price p41"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-5">Tostadas</h3>

    <p class="item item-38">Beef</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>2.85</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Chicken</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>2.85</span>
    <p class="item item-40">Bean</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>2.49</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-6">Burritos</h3>

    <p class="item item-38">Red Chili</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>4.49</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Carne Asada</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>4.90</span>
    <p class="item item-40">California</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>4.90</span>
    <p class="item item-38">Machaca</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Mixed</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-40">Beef</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-38">Chicken</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Beans</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>1.90</span>
    <p class="item item-40">Fish</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-38">Carnitas</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Chimichanga</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>5.85</span>
    <p class="item item-40">Chile Relleno</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>4.49</span>
    <p class="item item-38">Adobada</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Green Chile</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>4.49</span>
    <p class="item item-40">Shrimp</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>5.65</span>
    <p class="item item-38">Cabeza</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>4.75</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Pollo Asado</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>4.75</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-10">Breakfast Burritos</h3>
    
    <p class="item item-21">Suasage & Egg</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>4.09</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Ham & Eggs</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.09</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Bacon & Eggs</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.09</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Steak & Chorizon</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.75</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Picodegallo eggs & cheese</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>3.95</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Chorizo & Eggs</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.85</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Chorizo & Eggs</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.09</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section id="hours">
  <div class="container">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae dolorum, cumque quaerat nemo sed animi optio molestias? Minus ipsa expedita fuga eaque, odio animi fugiat! Necessitatibus, cumque non tempore mollitia doloremque quis aliquam assumenda, optio odit maxime, nam laboriosam! Qui, a, veritatis. Nam quos, esse, magni doloribus atque iusto voluptate sunt, asperiores officiis quaerat molestias. Mollitia vitae laudantium veritatis enim id modi minus suscipit, aut itaque nostrum eos odio sunt alias rem distinctio iste cum, voluptatum maxime commodi recusandae ea. Recusandae, dolorem, vel voluptatem sit ex quasi! Porro expedita sapiente ipsa quisquam. Eligendi quam vitae quasi maxime, incidunt nesciunt aliquam dignissimos eius, tempore. Sapiente, libero veritatis. Voluptatem amet labore, consequatur in, nam vitae quasi voluptatum quam illum totam autem, ex sunt. Natus sapiente aliquam porro. Culpa impedit aspernatur, similique, incidunt earum voluptates illum distinctio consequuntur dicta? Accusamus eaque et, vero hic temporibus! Ullam sed repellendus est sit distinctio nulla, iusto ab doloribus modi vel perspiciatis. Animi, distinctio, laborum ducimus numquam mollitia voluptatem nam illo ipsum officia excepturi velit natus eligendi tempora iusto praesentium dolorum suscipit in exercitationem ut eum! Facere, enim! Quos optio in ratione ab necessitatibus animi architecto ea eligendi libero, placeat, saepe modi, soluta suscipit repudiandae nihil eaque exercitationem! Asperiores rem consequuntur tenetur praesentium similique et aliquam natus recusandae, quam itaque nam nostrum tempore dolorem perspiciatis ab quidem amet eaque cupiditate, nesciunt doloremque repellendus eligendi a tempora nulla cumque! Totam esse saepe quaerat quis architecto quod dolorem! Velit natus libero, provident repellat delectus cum nihil cumque, architecto. Dolorem illum asperiores corporis, cupiditate recusandae obcaecati earum natus totam nemo, magni et facere vitae similique dolor qui a, saepe quia veniam. Delectus, dolorem nesciunt tenetur ipsam qui ea accusamus! Eos quis harum explicabo quidem nesciunt magnam tempora reprehenderit tenetur, eaque sed temporibus aliquid, quo vero provident cum id. Dolore, doloremque.
  </div>
 </section>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things. Firstly, remove `margin-top: -300px` on hours section. Secondly, your hours section is not high enough, it might because you don't have content inside that section currently, but at least it needs `100vh` to make the page scroll to its top.

Check this [link](https://codepen.io/he_wang/pen/zyNGWb) out

Or you can simply use this code:

```
 #hours .container {
   background-color: #339966;
   width: 100vw;
   /*   margin-top: -300px; */
   min-height: 200vh;
   z-index: 1111;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add position:relative to #hours .container

```
#hours .container {
    background-color: #339966;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    position: relative;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QzdbVm

Answer (score 0):

When using z-index add positions properties because it only works when you specify position properties.

```css
#hours .container {
    background-color: #5f75bd;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    z-index: 1111;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```